# Make Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 look like Expression Blend

Tags: visual-studio, ide, themes

I recently started using a black theme for Visual Studio and love it. I would also like it if I could get all the panels to change colour to something more like the Expression suite of programs. Im guessing this is not possible in VS2008, but can it be done in VS2010 since it uses WPF?

Comment: Thanks for the -1 and then not letting me know why. I'm new here. Some feedback where i am going wrong would have been helpful

Comment: Someone has marked the question for closure so maybe that's why. However it's an appropriate question for this site and I've upvoted you. Please stick around and don't let this initial experience put you off!

Comment: Thanks, i did a search and there were many questions on what people considered their favourite theme so i felt that it would be okay to ask about this sort of thing. I'll stick strictly to scripting questions from now on till i have settled in I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at a company that build online training products.  We have some good research data that says dark colors in higher frequencies cause less eye strain.  While this does't really answer your question, dark blue with white and yellow text colors seems to be best for extended viewing.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out in VS 2010 you can go:-

Tools ...
Extension Manager ...

And look for a extension called Visual Studio Theme Editor (It seems one of the highest ranked).

This tool seems to allow you to modify the theme in VS 2010. Don't think you can make it look like blend as such, but you can change the colours at least.

Feels kinda weird coming back to (I think) my first question and answering it after all this time. Hope this helps the 2 people that favourited it :)

Also found this:
http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme